# Vectorizing a for loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vectorization

In MATLAB, given a matrix `A`, I want to create a matrix `B` containing elements of matrix `A` as a percentage of the first column elements. The following code does it:

```
A = randi(5,6);

B = zeros(size(A,1), size(A,2));
for kk = 1:size(A,2)
    B(:,kk) = (A(:,kk).*100)./ A(:,1)-100;
end
```

However, how could I achieve the same result in a single line through vectorization? Would `arrayfun` be useful in this matter?

Comment: The outer loop over `ii` doesn't do anything, so you can just divide the entire  matrix by the first column.

Comment: @beaker I just edited the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) in this case:

```
B = bsxfun(@rdivide, 100 * A, A(:, 1)) - 100;
```

What your code is doing is taking each column of your matrix `A` and dividing by the first column of it.  You are doing some extra scaling, such as multiplying all of the columns by 100 before dividing, and then subtracting after.  `bsxfun` internally performs broadcasting which means that it will temporarily create a new matrix that duplicates the first column for as many columns as you have in `A` and performs an element-wise division.  You can complete your logic by pre-scaling the matrix by 100, then subtracting by 100 after.

With MATLAB R2016b, there is no need for `bsxfun` and you can do it natively with arithmetic operations:

```
B = (100 * A) ./ A(:,1) - 100;
```